# email verification code - to uniqid or not?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm writing a simple user system where I want users to verify their email address (like pretty much every other site). What do you think is the best way to generate this string that would then be used to verify a user?

At first I thought I would just use `uniqid()`, but as I am thinking more about it what type of security concerns should I keep in mind.

PS. I am using PDO w/ prepare (MySQL); what other sanitizing should I be doing with my db operations?

Comment: I would do `md5(microtime())` to generate unique hash, then you'll just store the hash somewhere in varchar type column

Comment: @serg: that's not unique. it's unlikely, but entirely possible, for 2+ hits to come in and get the same microtime. it's by far better to do a hash of other guaranteed unique values. users's email address, database record primary key, various salting values, blah blah blah

Comment: @Marc B yeah i was thinking of hashing their email. What other sanitizing should I be doing while using PDO?

Comment: @Serg not only does that fail to guarantee uniqueness, its predictable. If an attacker wanted to confirm himself for an email address he/she doesn't own, that is a small set of values to attempt. Remember most servers use ntp, and the time is almost certainly accurate to within 50ms (and probably 10).

Comment: predictable, absolutely agree. Better to hash email + some secret string (or other unique way to combine strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be able to generate a string that's sufficiently hard to reproduce externally. For instance, a simple SHA1 hash of the user's email address would be easy to replicate and wouldn't be suitable.

Due to the way a hashing function works, though, you could always spike in a "secret" and it would work well enough. For instance, generate a long random string constant that's used for this purpose and append that to the user's email address, then hash it. You can also generate random strings as verification tokens.

Whatever method you use, be sure to record the verification token you sent to the user in a column of their record, and index your table on this column so retrieval time is quick. Later you'll be doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE verification_token=?
```

If you can find an entry matching that token you know it's a valid user and they can be flagged as verified.

Answer (score -2):

The best solution for the users - doesn't use email verification. This is very old and boring technology (a lot of users use 10minutemail).

Comment: I like how you point this out, and then don't elaborate on alternatives. That's like saying don't buy XXX there is a better one; meanwhile the person you are talking to just sits there waiting....